# Unable to install from downloaded disk image file

Tags: macos

My Mac G4 (running OS X 10.3.9) won't install from any .dmg file I download. It keeps popping up a message: "name of setup & no mountable file system" or "application file cannot be found". Is there some setting I need to change to get around this problem as I need to install some extra programs urgently.

Comment: Poorly worded question. Need more info. Detailed error messages. Possible duplicate: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9364/cant-install-mac-os-x-combo-update-10-6

Answer (score 2):

It is likely the disk images do not support Mac OS X 10.3.9.

The command line tool used to create disk images is called [hdiutil](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/hdiutil.1.html%20%27hdiutil%20Manual%27). This [hdiutil manual](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/hdiutil.1.html%20%27hdiutil%20Manual%27) page documents the DMG format's history and compatibility with older editions of Mac OS X.

[hdiutil manual page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/hdiutil.1.html%20%27hdiutil%20Manual%27)

Answer (score 1):

I think a lot of the DMGs that you find on the internets today are compressed, which older disk utilities may not support. You might be SOL here  =\ (unless you upgrade or has another computer with a newer OS)