# osx update error

Tags: snow-leopard, software-update

I just tried installing an update on my OSX(10.6) and I got the following error :-

> Some of the selected updates couldn't be saved.
>
> The file “SUBaseSystemCombo10.6.8.pkg” couldn’t be found on the server
>   “swcdn.apple.com”.
>
> The file “iTunesX.pkg” couldn’t be found on the server
>   “swcdn.apple.com”.

I'm not sure why the error happens. Could someone suggest a way to diagnose or get past the issue? Thanks.

Comment: Also, in 2018 - you might have better luck using a combo update to get to 10.6.8 or so first. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9364/why-cant-i-install-os-x-10-6-6-combined-updates?

Answer (score 1):

Typically this is a momentary situation where Apple is updating it's servers; Manually download them from:

- http://support.apple.com/downloads/

Or you can try back later...

Comment: Ah I see thanks - do I have to download updates manually? Or is there a single OSX update that I can download and use for 10.6?

Comment: @wheee, if you still can't update I would recommend downloading the following first:

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1512

— Then after you install it, try to run the software update again. If you can post a reply as to whether or not it helped solve the problem we can go from there. Manually downloading the updates hopefully will be unnecessary (and for multiple/concurrent updates I'd try to avoid it); if you need to update manually though, i'll try and help make it less time consuming for you.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I tried to download and install the update, however, I recently reinstalled my OSX and an having 10.6.3 - it seems that I can install the update your mentioned above only if im on 10.6.8

Comment: @wheee oh sorry, i didn't realize you were using 10.6.3 — try installing this one instead: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL676, then try  > Software Update... and let us know if you're successful with updating automatically.